# ASP.NET reading content from inner octet/stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, raw-data

I have HTTP request from some device with body:

```
--18113960011
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"; filename="data"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

�o��\��Հ��vx�+�#:�țdV+
Iy@o*,cޙ��k
--18113960011--
```

And I accept this request in ASP.NET Web API controller. How I can read this inner data

```
�o��\��Հ��vx�+�#:�țdV+
Iy@o*,cޙ��k
```

as array of bytes using native way (no using substring extracting)?

Comment: And how I can pack array of bytes to same construction nextly

Comment: Did you carried out some research yourself? Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188759/how-to-receive-a-byte-array-and-json-in-a-web-api-controller) SO question for some inspiration.